# Visual studio 2019 - package manager GUI freezes when using local Nuget repository but when fiddler is working it works fast

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, fiddler

I am using local Nuget repository on air gap environment.

When I use the Nuget package manager of Visual Studio 2019 and I search  for package or even when moving from Browse to Installed and vice versa the application freezes for at least half a minute.

When I tried to investigate the issue with Fiddler I have found out that as long as Fiddler is up The problem is solved.

How come it works fine when fiddler is on?

Comment: As the system has no network connection all network requests will time-out. May be the used tool has very long time-out configured and retries multiple times, Fiddler instead may have smaller time-out values. Additionally Fiddler can cache those server that are not reachable preventing to try to establish the connection again and again. To understand what is going wrong Wireshark is the better tool as it does not changes the system behavior.

Answer (score -2):

Quite strange and not sure whether fiddler finally caused the problem or some suitable factor.

Please try the following steps to check your VS environment:

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**.

**2)** close VS, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`, and then restart VS to test again.

**3)** type `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol=[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol-bOR [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` under **Tools**--> **Nuget Package Manager**--> **Package Manager Console**

**4)** close vs, delete global `nuget.config` file under `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\NuGet`, restart to test again.

**5)** reset vs settings under **Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**--> **Reset vs settings**

**6)** type `devenv /safemode` under Developer Command prompt for VS to start a new pure VS to test again.

**7)** [repair vs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update it if there is a new release version.

**Besides**, as your choice, you could initialize your VS. Close VS, just delete the whole `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx` folder.